# What effect does a space have before the class name?

Tags: html, css

My aim is to have this class apply only when set on `<img>` tags. It only works when there is no space between the tag name and the class name, but doesn't when there is. I have seen style sheets with spaces in the signature, so I'm sure it must be valid in some contexts.

What is the difference between:

```
img.approved-photo {
    // no space
}
```

and

```
img .approved-photo {
    // has a space
}
```

Comment: It's to select a child from the element before. ie: An element with class `.approved-photo` within an `img`.

Comment: To apply to the element itself, you need to remove the space.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors

Comment: *"Does not show any research effort."* - I.e. the question has been asked before, there's ample documentation available and any CSS tutorial teaches this. This question didn't need to be asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one applies to an image with class "approved-photo", the second one to an element with class "approved-photo" which has an *img* element as ancestor.